# Why arccos(2) have value in complex numbers even though its $D_f [-1,1]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I've seen that arccos has $D_f [-1,1]$ however when putting arccos(2) into wolframalpha, I get the complex number result if I understand it correctly. Why is it so?

If true, should not $D_f$ be differently precised?

Comment: If you are working with real numbers then $\arccos$ is defined only in the interval $[-1,1]$. But if you allow complex numbers then this function is defined in the whole complex plane.

Comment: @Mark Thank you. I've been just wondering if there should be always precised that we are working just with real numbers. Because in many definitions, or basics about this function I see that $D_f = [-1,1] $ but there is not precisely written that we are working just with real numbers. Because for me it seems, like it is not well defined if we did not define that we were working just with real numbers.

Comment: It depends what book you are using. If it is about real analysis then it will obviously work only with real numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working within $\mathbb R$ then $arcos (2)$ does not exist. But in the complex plane there are infinitely many solutions of the equation $\cos(z)=2$.